# Jade/pug change layout if radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am looking for a way, to swap the layout of my site between to options.

I got this form right now that I use:

```
form(action="/xxx" method="post")

                .row
                    .col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-4.col-xs-8
                        .input-group
                            select.form-control.text-center(name="selectOptionVat")
                                each taxRate in taxRates
                                    option.text-center= taxRate
                            span.input-group-btn
                                button.btn.btn-success(type="submit") #{getText('Submit')}
```

The form is used to update everything in a table.

I want to add another form that gets visible once the user clicks one radio button in the table, and then also hides this form. So swap between the two of them :-)

I know I could do this in many ways, but if it is possible, I have various reasons that I really want to do it only through Jade/pug :-)

Also, if the user deselect all radio buttons again, the original form should be shown again, and the other one hidden once again - but I suppose I can implement this myself, in case anyone got any hints of how to solve this.

Comment: Please try to implement and if stuck on particular problems ask here. Hint: Briefly you have defined what needs doing, just implement those using css classes that can be toggled to show hide, and use javascript onclick of radio button to do the toggling.

Comment: Well, I did try to implement it, but didn't find a solution. I guess I could do it in different ways, but for various reasons I really prefer to do this by Jade/pug alone, if possible :-)

Comment: From what I understand jade/pug is a templating engine, so it can do a one time initial rendering based on your initial state, but once rendered on the browser, it will not have any control over dynamic changes. You will need to use javascript for that. If I am not wrong jade compilation happens serverside.

Comment: I agree with you, just hoped it could be possible with some if statements and such, but guess not. Thanks for your help, time and advice :-)

Comment: No problem, thanks to your question I did do a bit of digging into jade, and it appears it can be used as a client side templating engine too: http://timnew.me/blog/2014/05/26/use-jade-as-client-side-template-engine/, but I still think it can render once and then you would need javascript for dynamic changes to rendered template. Have used jade a while ago briefly, but that was for precompiling templates using grunt.

Comment: That looks cool - when look more into that asap :-) Thanks! - cant vote you as you only commented :-( Sorry.

Comment: No probs. That isn't really an answer to your question, to be fair. Just a possible thing to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using JavaScript (and jQuery) as suggested. The solution is not so short as I hoped, but here it is, in case it helps anyone else.

https://jsfiddle.net/ushdo9cu/

```
$('body').on('mouseup', 'input[type="radio"]', function () {
var radio = $(this);
uncheck_radio_before_click(radio); });
```